# Stack Overflow doesn't accept edits that only address formatting

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I've run into a small problem just today. I was reviewing a question and tried to re-format the question since the OP seemed to have missed some lines that clearly were part of the code (s)he was trying to post.

However, once I was finished, I received a message telling me my edits were rejected because they required more than 4 non-blank edits to pass.

The first time it happened I cancelled my edits. The second time I corrected some minor grammatical mistakes.

Is this a new feature? How else should I have proceeded?

Comment: No, this is not a new feature. You are expected to make substantial edits, to prevent flooding the suggested edit queue.

Comment: Fix all the problems in a post, not just the one thing you saw first. And if that doesn't take you over the minimum, you're out of luck.

Comment: OK. I guess I just hadn't stumbled onto this feature.

Comment: See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggested edits should address all the issues in a post, and shouldn't be too minor. Your suggestion gets reviewed by a few different people before it's accepted, so we don't want to create lots of trivial review work, and also, since it's worth a little rep (2) it should be more than 5 seconds' effort.

The [original blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) states:

There are a few additional requirements when submitting an edit suggestion:

- You must enter a reasonable comment describing your edit.
- To prevent noise and friction, your change must be more than 6 characters.

---

Maybe there's more you can edit:

- Is there some code indentation that can be improved for clarity?
- Can it be phrased better?
- Can you correct the spelling and grammar?

Your aim should be to make it the best possible way to say what was originally said (certainly without changing what was said).

Once you reach reputation of 2000 you can edit any question or answer without going through review, at which point we trust you to do a good job without restricting you.